# how to check ping response of multiple website in django based site?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have created one website which contains different company application in bootstrap **cart** format. This cart is showing the application version and allowing the user to download it by clicking on the button.

Requirement:

Now I am trying to implement functionally where it will show whether the site is online/reachable or not by a green color dot. I have tried the below code but I found that only for a few 1 sites it is showing green color and for the remaining, it is showing False.

Also found that the site is taking time to load the **home page** I have seen this functionality implemented in a few websites. Can anyone suggest to me how to implement it in the best way?

Please find the below code.

**views.py**(showing only logic code)

```
data = {}
    for singlesite in allsites:
        site=singlesite.product_by
        try:
            subprocess.check_call(['ping', '-c', '1', str(site)])
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            online = False
            data['online'] = online
            print('Checking The Ping Response:', online)
        else:
            online = True
            data['online'] = online
            print('Checking The Ping Response:', online)
```

in the above code, *product_by* means I am taking it from model form.

HTML code.

```html
.logged-in {
  color: green;
  font-size: 8px;
}

.logged-out {
  color: red;
  font-size: 8px;
}

  {% if online %}
                                               <span class="logged-in">●</span>
                                               {% else %}
                                               <span class="logged-out">●</span>
                                               {% endif %}
```

Any help on this how to handle delay and implement this functionality will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Pinging for some websites won't work because they might have blocked pinging at firewall level.

Comment: For loading issue you might want to use a task queue like celery.